# Django pagination by date (week)

Tags: python, html, django

I am making a website that displays this week's soccer games from the day you open the website to six days later (current week), and i want to paginate by date.

example `<previous> <19 feb - 25 feb> <next>` then when i press next `<previous> <26 feb - 4 march> <next>`

---

in views.py.

matches is a list of dictionaries, each dictionary is a single game that contains the date of the game and other info and its sorted by date

```
def home(request):
start = datetime.now().date()
end = today + timedelta(6)

matches = request_games(today, after_week)

return render(request, "sporty/home.html",{
    "matches": matches,
    "start" : start,
    "end": end
    })
```

---

in home.html

```
{% for match in matches %}
    //match info
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is how to paginate by weeks, once i open the website shows matches from that day to one week later then when you press next takes you to next week of matches, and all matches are stored in a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to create sets of different weeks, perhaps for the whole season, you would want create another dictionary comprised of those dictionaries of matches you have created, accessing each 'matches' dictionary when you paginate.

Then at this point you'd want to determine what dictionary to look at by a radio button or some javascript function. The link below talks about the proper way of going about using javascript and django, and while you cant use a javascript variable in a django template, you can work around it using ajax.

[use javascript variable in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23879733/use-javascript-variable-in-django-template)

You could also create a div element for each matches dictionary. Then, in your css file, set each element to `display:none`. You can then access the element from javascript and change the display of the div element so that it is showing when a certain button is pushed.

```
function changeGames(){
   document.getElementById('div1').style.display= 'block' ;
   document.getElementById('div2').style.display= 'none' ;
}
```