# Cannot have any URLs with slugs. NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I'm a begginer grasping at straws with difficulty dealing with the django slug url system and these NoReverseMatch errors that make no sense to me even after reading the docs.

I have a django project. In one of the views, I pass a list of geoJSON features into a template, and show them on a map. I want to have each feature act as a clickable 'link' to a view that will show stuff about it. The following is part of the template that has those features that I want to click on:

```
//part of the template:
<script type="text/javascript">
...
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.on('click', function (e) {
        window.location.href = "{% url 'polls:areadetail' feature.properties.myslug%}";
        });
     }
```

(I have confirmed that feature.properties.myslug does in fact contain the slug I want).

The url pattern I want to go to:

```
urlpatterns = [...
url(r'^areadetail/(?P<areaslug>[-\w]+)/$', views.AreaDetail, name='areadetail'),]
```

And the view it relates to:

```
def AreaDetail(request, areaslug):
    area = get_object_or_404(Area, nameslug=areaslug)
    return render(request, 'polls/areadetail.html', {'area':area})
```

The issue I get is, by  doing what I show and placing that url reference inside that template I show above, that I want to be able click on, that template won't even work at all, giving me a 'Error during template rendering' full page error info that starts with:

> NoReverseMatch at /polls/areas/
>   Reverse for 'areadetail' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'polls/areadetail/(?P[-\w]+)/$']

Any help would be immensely appreciated

---

**EDIT part1**: As I've said in response to falsetru, I'm sure feature.properties.myslug has in fact got a slug expression in it.
**EDIT2**: Based on something I found in a django ticket, I've made a slight change in the url regex at urls.py, from `(?P<areaslug>[-\w]+)/$` to `(?P<areaslug>[-\w]+)?/$` and now the error is:

> Page not found (404)
>   Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/areadetail// Raised by: polls.views.AreaDetail

**Is it possible that because the `"{% url 'polls:areadetail' feature.properties.myslug%}"` bit is inside javascript, that feature.properties.myslug is not being inserted there correctly? Like some sort of brackets are needed here?**

Comment: clearly `feature.properties.myslug` is evaluating to `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging around I've found the answer to why doesn't this work in another question at:

> [How to pass javascript variable to django custom filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952156/how-to-pass-javascript-variable-to-django-custom-filter)

The answer to it by Ludwik Trammer says:

> Django templates are build on the server side, while JavaScript is executed on the client side.
>   That means that template code is always executed before JavaScript (as
>   it is executed by the server, before the page is sent to the client).
>   As a consequence it is absolutely impossible to mix JavaScript and
>   Django code the way you want to.

Which clearly applies here. I was focused on problems with the URL template, regex on the urls.py file etc. when the problem was that no matter what I did, because it's in a javascript section, run client-side, that URL template will always be incomplete no matter what I do, therefore being an impossible solution to what I want.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, `feature.properties.myslug` is empty or has no value.

Make sure the `feature.properties.myslug` is passed correctly from view.

- Comment out `{% url .. %}` temporarily.
- Print `{{ feature }}`, `{{ feature.properties }}`, `{{ feature.properties.myslug }}` to see if which part is missing.
- Fix view accordingly.
- Uncomment `{% url .. %}`.

Comment: I have tried it. In fact, if I remove the {%url...} and examine page souce, I can find :(...) "Feature", "properties": {"myslug": "an-example" (...) where 'an-example' is the slug. I've even used a javascript alert('feature.properties.myslug'); in it's place and it confirms this, as 'an-example' appears after a click. It's as if the {%url...} part simply ignores anything I put in there.