# How to split a string inside of django template

Tags: django

I am passing a strings consists of characters separated with comma like `A, B, C, ..` to django template, using javascript.

This is my code:

```
 {% with list_of_words = wizard.form.tags.split(',') %}
    {% for tag in list_of_words  %}
      <a href="" ><span class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-xs mb-3">
        <span class="h6 text-uppercase">
          <div class="badge badge-rounded-circle badge-danger-soft mt-1 mr-0">
            <i class="fe fe-check"></i>
          </div>
          {{ tag }}
          </span></span></a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endbwith %}
```

where `{{wizard.form.tags}}` returns a long string, however I need to separate it inside of the template to style it. Is there solution for that?

P.S. Just note that I can't probably add method to the model as the value inside the `{{wizard.form.tags}}` are passed by js and not reading from database.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so first in your app directory create a file called `filters.py` and add this to it:

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter


register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name='split')
@stringfilter
def split(value, key):
    """
        Returns the value turned into a list.
    """
    return value.split(key)
```

Then go to your `settings.py` and add this to the **TEMPLATES**:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'libraries': { # <----- add this
                'filter_tags': 'your_app_name_here.filters' # switch with your app name
            }
        },
    },
]
```

Then in your **template**:

```
{% load filter_tags %}

{% with wizard.form.tags|split:"," as tags %}
    {% for tag in tags %}
        {{ tag }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it gives an error: Invalid block tag on line 126: 'set', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: I just replaced the code, but gives the same error

Comment: Show the string you are trying to pass and is it contained within a `wizard` or within the `wizard.form.tags` ?

Comment: it's like `A, B, C,....`, I tried also with `{% set list_of_words = wizard.form.tags.split(',') %}`. I am trying to replace it with `with`

Comment: Can you update your question with your current code?

Comment: you can also try this: `{% list_of_words = {{ wizard.form.tags }}.split(', ') %}`

Comment: Invalid block tag on line 126: 'list_of_words', expected 'endblock'. I also tried to add `{% endblock %}`

Comment: Can you show what do you see when you just render the string?

Comment: I expect to make every tag in string gets like a badge/button, but now all the string gets one single badge, and it's because string does not get splited

Comment: try running `pip install Jinja2` and then use the first regular `set`

Comment: actually nevermind, this answer is wrong, looks like `set` only works in Flasks templating

Comment: Yes tha't why I was using `with` rather than `set`, thanks for your time

Comment: Check out the edit, this should work with django

Comment: I get a weird error: `'BoundField' object has no attribute 'split'`. I am following this https://moonbooks.org/Articles/How-to-create-a-list-of-items-from-a-string-in-a-Django-template-/

Comment: Weird, it worked for me, make sure you set the correct path in your settings libraries, i'll update the answer

Comment: ah then I need to debug if works for you, maybe it's something related to wizard form as see in the updated picture

Comment: Check out my edit and let me know if it worked

Comment: I think problem is not in your code, I just replaced `wizard.form.tags` with `A, B, C` it works. Problem is `wizard.form.tags` which does not hold a string

Comment: Then you'll have to convert it using javascript and pass the coverted object as a string :) btw thanks for accepting my answer :)

Comment: thanks, but as mentioned in the following question, this solution is impossible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20952666/10765156

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with your app?