# Add Javascript string variable INSIDE a django template variable

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I have a chart that is populated by django template variables. I have an update chart function that updates the data after certain buttons are clicked. Instead of writing the same js function 7x, can I update the javascript function to call the correct data within a Django template variable?

Basically, the btn_id will either be A, B, C, D, E, or F and I want the django template variable to display the correct data based on the btn_id value.

```
    var results = {{ all_test_results.A.curve_series.curve_series }}.map(function(val, i) {
        return val === 'None' ? null : val;
    });
```

becomes

```
    const btn_id = this.id.slice(-1); # A, B, C, D, etc

    var results = {{ all_test_results.{{ btn_id }}.curve_series.curve_series }}.map(function(val, i) {
        return val === 'None' ? null : val;
    });
```

[image]

I am sure there is a simple way to inject a js string into a Django template variable, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass javascript variable to django custom filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952156/how-to-pass-javascript-variable-to-django-custom-filter)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I understand the django tag is executed on the server, I wasn't actually looking to inject the button value into the syntax of the django tag, I was looking for a workaround solution like the AJAX method raphael outlined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple, no**

> I am sure there is a simple way to inject a js string into a Django
> template variable, right?

Here's the problem.  `{{ all_test_results.A.curve_series.curve_series }}` is handled by the *server*, which is handled by Django, which takes this tag, and fills it in with the data and returns an HTML document back to the *client*.  Now it is the *client*, that is the end user, who clicks on say a button **C**, but how does Django, who lives on the server know about this?  It doesn't, and that's why this is not so simple.

**Solution**

When the user clicks **C**, you can have a simple AJAX request sent from the client to the server, with this information.  The server can then send back the value of `all_test_results.C.curve_series.curve_series` (you will have to write a query for this, you wouldn't be able to use a variable in place of **C** here), which can be received by your JavaScript, so that you don't have to do this 7 times.

**Details**

```py
# views.py

from django.http import JsonResponse

def get_result(request, letter):
    return JsonResponse({'answer': [result of your query that uses the variable, "letter", which corresponds to the letter the user clicked, here]})
```

Add a path to this view

```py
# urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('get_result/<str:letter>', views.get_result, name='get_result')
]
```

In your template you have your buttons with values that can be targeted by JavaScript, and the container that will show the result:

```html
<button type="button" class="result_btns" value="A" id="A">A</button>
<button type="button" class="result_btns" value="B" id="B">B</button>
<button type="button" class="result_btns" value="C" id="C">C</button>
<button type="button" class="result_btns" value="D" id="D">D</button>
<button type="button" class="result_btns" value="E" id="E">E</button>
<button type="button" class="result_btns" value="F" id="F">F</button>

<div id="result">Result will appear here</div>
```

And finally the JavaScript, which will make the AJAX request, get the response from the server, and finally update the HTML with the result:

```js
async function get_result(e) {

    // Make the AJAX request to the server:
    const response = await fetch('/get_result/' + e.target.value);
    // Once the response is received, turn it into json format:
    const result = await response.json();
    // Update the div you want to carry the result:
    // NOTE: you should not use innerHTML here.
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result.answer;
}

// Get all the buttons of class result_btns from the HTML
let btns = document.querySelectorAll("button");
// For each button, create an event listener, that will
// send to the function get_result, it's value
btns.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', get_result);
});
```

Comment: This is very helpful, I was able to include a for loop and if forloop.last statement to condense a huge button list down into 2 elements with the button values triggering a chart js update and giving the user a creative interface for interactive data.

Comment: I'm glad I was of help, @RichardModad!  Your forloop idea is great.  Personally, I thought your question was useful and up voted it yesterday.